# kde folder widget custom icon?

Tags: kde, directory, widgets

I want to set a custom Icon on my folder widget that I have on one of my panels. How if possible do I do this? or is there a similar widget I can use that can do this, with shortcuts for specific launcher files?

Answer (score 0):

After unlocking the widgets, drag and drop the folder you want to the panel, and choose icon from the menu that will appear. Then right click the icon and choose icon settings.
Click on the icon to browse different icon.